# Should we say "fruits and vegetables" or "fruit and vegetables"?

Tags: difference, countable-nouns, food

Which one of the following is correct?

> 1. fruit***s*** and vegetables
> 2. fruit and vegetables

Could you please explain it to me?

Answer (score 5):

From the [Wikipedia page on "mass nouns"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun)...

> *- the word "fruit" is (usually) non-count, whereas "vegetables" is a plural count form.*

What this means is that for many (particularly, *older* and/or *British*) speakers, explicitly pluralising the word in contexts such as *"I'm a strict vegetarian - I only eat **fruits** and vegetables"* sounds a bit "odd".

But over recent decades, [particularly in America](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=eat%20fruit%20and%20vegetables,eat%20fruits%20and%20vegetables&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=), the "regular" plural has become much more common...

[image]

I don't think there's *really* any difference between *fruit* and *fruits* when combined with *...and vegetables* as part of the "collective" expression. Being an older Brit myself, I must admit *fruits* makes me think more of *individual pieces of fruit*, but that's just because I don't hear the collocation so often as Americans.

It's also interesting to note another point made in that Wikipedia link. In BrE (but not so much in AmE), the informal/slang term *veg* has been [widely adopted as the "non-count" version of *vegetables*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fruit%20and%20veg,fruits%20and%20veg&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=). And whereas *fruits and vegetables* sounds "a bit odd" to me, *fruits and veg* (which [sometimes turns up in AmE usage](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fruit%20and%20veg,fruits%20and%20veg&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)) sounds positively *weird*.

Comment: +1. To me, *fruits* makes me think of *different varieties of fruit*; that is, I'd say "Eat your fruit and vegetables!" but "We have a wide selection of fruits and vegetables here today."

Comment: @WendiKidd: Well, I suppose by implication so do I. After all, if there was only one kind of each I'd be encouraging my kids to eat their [asparagus and strawberries](http://www.choosingraw.com/asparagus-and-strawberry-salad-with-balsamic-and-basil/) (or whatever it was). But being a Brit I can say my apple tree is *bearing **a lot of fruit*** this year. Are you more likely to say yours is *bearing **many fruits**?* Or does it not work like that for you because they're *all apples?*

Comment: ... I think I've got it now. *Fruits* works like *peoples*.

Comment: Yes, exactly! *Peoples* is a great comparison. And I'd use *fruit* for the tree, yeah.